# Load variable from class in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, rss

I feel stupid, and I am sleepless all because I want to get my app to work the way I want it to.

I am trying to load the author variable from one class into a new class, but the new class is returning (null).

I'm afraid I'm on the go right now, so I couldn't look at other examples. I'm typing this on my phone, I'll try my best to type the code.

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>
...
<body><h1>%@</h1>
<hr />%@<hr />%@<hr />
</body><html>", self.title, author, userText];
```

So I made the variable of author in the .h file:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *author;`

And then I made it load the author string from the master class:

```
BDNMasterViewController *mvc;
author = mvc.author;
```

And then I made it log the Author in the master class:

```
NSString *authortext = @"Author: ";
authortext = [authortext stringByAppendingString:author];
NSLog(authortext);
```

It logs the author correctly. It doesn't show the author here:

[image]

the (null) in the picture is what I'm trying to fix.

What mistakes did I make? (Since I'm sleep deprived and everything)

EDIT:
I did import the Master in the Detail

```
#import "BDNMasterViewController.h"
```

To look at the entire MasterViewController and DetailViewController:

http://pastebin.com/ykJQs2B2 - BDNMasterViewController.h

http://pastebin.com/xFbQc8UJ - BDNMasterViewController.m

http://pastebin.com/SszmiAAh - BDNDetailViewController.h

http://pastebin.com/SRKiQ21G - BDNDetailViewController.m

Comment: Where is `*mvc` being assigned a value? It appears to be declared, but never set. If it is nil, then `mvc.author` will also be `nil`, since calling a method on `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize (created property  BDNMasterViewController *mvc in your BDNDetailViewController ) BDNDetailViewController and assign in it bDNDetailViewController.mvc = self; where self ivars of BDNMasterViewController;

Comment: Please edit your answer with code markers to make it more readable.